# How can I apply same style from element that changes in HTML to one that doesn't change in HTML?

Tags: jquery, css

I need this HTML to change from `fullwidth-header` to `fullwidth-header2`, then `fullwidth-header3`,4, 5, 6, and so on.

```
<div class="fullwidth-header">
      <div class="container custom-container">
            <div class="fullwidth-header-block">
                Residents
                  <p>Manage your home utility account.</p>
            </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

Here is the small notch inside the top, white navigation.

```
.notch-nav .current a:before, .fullwidth-header {
    background: blue;
}
```

It's currently green. I need it to be blue (essentially, it should have the same exact background as fullwidth-header, 2, 3, 4, etc, depending on which full-width header is in the HTML.

http://codepen.io/Goatsy/pen/qNdyMB

If you check the pen, you'll see that when changing the HTML from fullwidth-header to fullwidth-header2, the backgrounds don't match.

How do I achieve the "matching" bg and small box without having to change anything else in the HTML besides fullwidth-header#?

I'm looking for any solution, CSS or jQuery. Preferably, CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your CSS, you have:

```
.notch-nav .current a:before, .fullwidth-header4 {
    background: green;
}
```

which is the same as writing:

```
.notch-nav .current a:before {
    background: green;
}

.fullwidth-header4 {
    background: green;
}
```

**In other words, the two style declarations aren't actually linked in any way.** That's why the `.notch-nav a` thing will always be the last color you declare it in CSS (keeps overriding previous ones).

--

**You have two main options at this point:**

1) Change the color via Javascript, (writing vanilla JS here but it's easily translated into JQuery) i.e.:

```
document.querySelector('.notch-nav .curent a:before').style.background = document.querySelector('.fullwidth-header').style.background
```

2) Re-structure your HTML so that the .notch-nav is nested INSIDE of an identifying parent, i.e:

```
<div class="fullwidth-header header2">
  <div class="notch-nav"></div>
</div>
```

Because then you could write CSS like this:

```
.header2 .notch-nav { /* something */ }
.header3 .notch-nav { /* something else */ }
... etc.
```

I would personally recommend restructuring the HTML slightly (option 2) instead of adding a script to do this.

Comment: I applied your option#2 suggestion. Worked great. Thank you for such a simple solution. :) http://codepen.io/Goatsy/pen/jrPvyd